# How to force a page to stay in horizontal orientation with xaml in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to force a page to stay in horizontal orientation with xaml in a WP8 app?

I.e. the page should only support horizontal and cannot be rotated back to portrait (to play fullscreen video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in page XAML:

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="LandscapeLeft"
```

If you want to know more, here's a MSDN documantation of the SupportedOrientation property:
[PhoneApplicationPage.SupportedOrientations Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.supportedorientations%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)